# How to locate the homepage of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry for posting my question here as I don't know where I should post it.

I am new to wordpress and now I need to amend the main webpage.

I logged in GoDaddy and I tried to find some files like index.html, index.php, but they are not the page I want.

Which file should I find?

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: CAn you clear more your question please? Do you want to find out homepage file in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check which theme you have selected from admin panel
then in folder look for `'themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME'`
There look for pages front-page.php/home.php/index.php  _ atleast one of these will be present.

Modif6y that file according to your need.

Comment: I can only see several folders, etc, logs, mail, public_html, ssl, tmp. Which folder should I try first?

Comment: I found index.php and it contains `define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Comment: In `wp-blog-header.php`, it cotains `if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

 $wp_did_header = true;

 // Load the WordPress library.
 require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

 // Set up the WordPress query.
 wp();

 // Load the theme template.
 require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );`

Comment: not that index.php... now go to folder 'wp-content/themes'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191505/discussion-between-alice-and-chan).